# Is Model.objects.update() in Django is synchronous? How to get updated rows after updating values?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm using Django with MySQL

I want to get effected rows after run `Model.objects.update()`

I have code below:

```
# 1
User.objects.filter(
        pk__in=ids,
        status=old_status,
    ).update(
        status=new_status,
        pre_update_key=uuid_str,
        updated_at=datetime.datetime.now(),
    )
# 2
updated_users = list(
    User.objects.filter(pre_update_key=uuid_str).values()
)
print(len(updated_users))
```

Results are different between environments

- Database 1: Users has 3000 rows
  => `len(updated_users) != 0 is correct`
- Database 2: Users has 300000 rows
  => `len(updated_users) = 0`

How can I get `updated_users` after #1 query is done completely?

Comment: The `update()` method runs a SQL `UPDATE table_name ... WHERE condition` query, this does not return the selected rows. Do you want to get the updated rows or the _number_ of updated rows?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I want to get updated rows, not number of rows

Comment: You can't get the updated rows (Rather you can have a database transaction where you get the rows that _will_ be updated first and _then_ run the update), your example though simply shows that you really want the number of updated rows

Comment: the problem is I have read from database rows that have updated `pre_update_key` before, but result is empty

Comment: My question would then be was there even any user matching your filter? `User.objects.filter(pk__in=ids, status=old_status)`? Can you add a `.count()` after that and print the results, i.e. `print(User.objects.filter(pk__in=ids, status=old_status).count())` Django is by default synchronous in nature unless you make it work asynchronously